# Use a single template to display entries from different channels?

Tags: templating

I'd like to use a single template to pull in entries from different channels based on url segment 2. But it seems I need to change the section attribute to match the url segment:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mySection').find() %}
```

Given that the url segment and section handle are different, can this be done?

For example the url segment might be `hotel-california` and the section handle of the section I want entries from could be `hotelCalifornia` or `hotelsInCalifornia`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, in situations like this (particularly if there's only a few items, and no easy way to automate it with inflection or similar,) I just use an array as a kind of dictionary.

```
{% set sectionHandlesBySegment = { 
    'hotel-california': 'hotelsCalifornia',
    'hotel-florida':    'hotelsFlorida' }
%}

{% if not craft.request.getSegment(2) in sectionHandlesBySegment|keys %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{% set sectionHandle = sectionHandlesBySegment[craft.request.getSegment(2)] %}
{% set hotels = craft.entries.section(sectionHandle) %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ["object syntax"](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#setting-the-parameters) of the ElementCriteriaModel, in combination with an [if-statement](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html):

```twig
// Checks if the 2. segment of the url is 'hotel-california'
{% if craft.request.getSegment(2) == 'hotel-california' %}
    {% set params = { section: 'hotelCalifornia' } %}
{% else %}
    {% set params = { section: 'anotherSection' } %}
{% endif %}

{% for entry in craft.entries(params) %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endif %}
```